# Django 'Model matching query does not exist.' error

Tags: python, django

I have a three simple models. User, Restaurant, Menu. A single user can have many restaurants, and each restaurant can have many Menus. I am using the generic Django CreateView for the Posting of the Restaurants and Menus to their respective models. This works for The restaurants, But fails for the Menus and I get a "Restaurant matching query does not exist" ERROR. I feel that it is a URL issue because I can reach the template if I input it manually, but fails when i use the button.

**VIEWS.py**

```
@login_required
def profile(request, pk):
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if not user.id == request.user.pk:
        raise PermissionDenied()
    else:
        context = {
            'user': user,
            'rests': Restaurant.objects.filter(account=request.user).order_by('-date'),
            'countRests': Restaurant.objects.filter(account=request.user).count(),
        }

        return render(request, 'restaurants/profile.html',context)

class RestCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'restaurants/makeRestaurant.html'
    form_class = RestCreateForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.account = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


def RestMenus(request, pk, name):
    rest = Restaurant.objects.get(name=name)
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if not user.id == request.user.pk:
        raise PermissionDenied()
    else:
        context = {
            'rest': rest,
            'user': user,
            'menus': Menu.objects.filter(restaurant=rest).order_by('-uploadDate'),
            'countMenus': Menu.objects.filter(restaurant=rest).count(),
        }
        return render(request, 'restaurants/menus.html',context)
    

class MenuCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'restaurants/makeMenu.html'
    form_class = MenuCreateForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.restaurant = self.request.restaurant
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**URLS.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/',profile, name='profile'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/createRest/', RestCreateView.as_view(), name='createRest'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/restaurant/<str:name>',RestMenus, name='RestDetail'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/restaurant/<str:name>/createMenu/', MenuCreateView.as_view(), name='createMenu'),
]
```

**FORMS.py**

```
class RestCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = [
            'name'
        ]


class MenuCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = [
            'name',
            'menuFile'
        ]
```

**Template (Menus.html)**

```
<section id="menusdash">
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <h3>{{ rest.name }}'s Menus</h3>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {% if countMenus == 0 %}
            <p>You have no Menus</p>
            {% else %}
            {% for menu in menus %}
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Menu Name: {{ menu.name }}</h5>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View Menu</a>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View QR Code</a>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button><a href="createMenu">Make a Menu</a></button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The URL seems to drop the str:name/ for the menu create template. Is it possible to pass a second argument using a CreateView, SO that i can have the PK and String:name in the url?

Comment: what happens when you try  "href='/profile/<int:pk>/restaurant/<str:name>/createMenu/'"?

Comment: @mattarello - Doesnt work, i get page not found

Comment: @mattarello - As i said in the question, it works when its statically typed. EG: "href='/profile/1/restaurant/PizzaPlace/createMenu/'"

Comment: then just pass the pk and the name from view to the template and do: "href='/profile/{{pk}}/restaurant/{{name}}/createMenu/'"